# BlueStacks: Is there a keyboard shortcut for the menu button?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, bluestacks

Instead of hitting the menu button with the mouse, is there any keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 6):

It's the "Menu" key on your keyboard usually located right next to the right "Ctrl" key. (It's the key that opens the right-click menu on windows)

Comment: Thanks but I'm using a Mac and that key doesn't work.

Comment: I think Dmod meant "alt" not "ctrl", though I do not believe he knows what he's talking about as that doesn't work either.